# How can I prevent vim from changing the % register when entering non-modifiable windows?

Tags: quickfix, vimgrep

My workflow revolves around having NerdTree opened with a quickfix at the the bottom and one file opened in a buffer.

I often grep within my file only by using the `%` shortcut in my grep command.

I then navigate to quickfix or NerdTree to look at something and rerun my grep command slightly tweaked. At this point the command no longer works as `@%` does not contain the name of my file anymore.

Could I keep entering non-modifiable buffers from updatding `@%`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`"%` is a read-only register. I doubt there is anything you can do to the register.

Instead of simply using `%` in your grep command, e.g. `:grep 'foo' %`, use `<c-r>` to put in the contents of the register, e.g. `:grep 'foo' <c-r>%`. This will paste/put the name of the file in the grep command. To tweak your grep simply do `q:` and go and edit your last grep (press return to run).

For more help see:

```
:h c_CTRL-R
:h c_%
:h q%
```